# how to create folder on amazon ec2 linux aws server using php

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2

```
$structure = '/upload';
if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

this is my code, but i m not been able to create directory.it shows me the error Failed to create folders.

Comment: do you have user permission to create the folders? looks like you are trying to create a folder in the root directory which requires root access.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create folders in the root directory with PHP as it does not have the permission to do that.

However, what you probably could do, is to create a folder in the root directory through an ssh terminal and use that folder for your application

```
sudo mkdir /myApp
```

Next, set write permissions to myApp folder

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 myApp
```

subsequently, you would be able to create your "uploads" folder in /myApp

Answer (score -1):

First ssh to your ec2 instance and change the ownership and permission of your web root folder, assuming your web root folder is located in /var/www/html you can do the following:

```
sudo chown -R /var/www/html apache.apache
```

The code above will make apache the owner of the web root direction and it's contents

```
sudo chmod -R 0775 /var/www/html
```

The code above sets the necessary permission for the web root folder and contents, you should edit as needed.

After that run your code you should be able to create the folder.