# mkdir with php 7.3 and centos 7

Tags: php, centos7

How create dir with php/centos 7? hosted witch aws EC2

i try:

```php
exec('sudo mkdir -p /nome_da_pasta');
shell_exec('sudo mkdir -p /nome_da_pasta');
mkdir("/nome_da_pasta", 0777);
```

```
drwxrwxrwx.  8 ec2-user ec2-user  104 May  8 21:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 12 ec2-user root      183 May  8 12:02 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  8 21:31 admin
drwxrwxrwx.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  9 01:04 cliente
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K May  8 21:31 loja
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:20 pHpServer
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:09 pHpServer-ADm
drwxrwxrwx.  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 May  8 12:15 pHpServer-PG
```

need create dir with php on hosted aws ec2

in ssh work, in php not work

```
PHP:

$cmd = '/bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/html/pHpServer-PG/api/dir.bash';
echo $cmd;
shell_exec($cmd);

BASH:

#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p nome_da_pasta
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576854/how-to-create-folder-on-amazon-ec2-linux-aws-server-using-php suggest that you can't do it for folders off /, try a sub-directory (after setting the appropriate permissions).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec might help with `sudo`.

Comment: @NigelRen is correct php and bash? because it is causing fatal error